# How does mass increase in black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass-energy, singularities

In the center of a black hole is a gravitational singularity, a one-dimensional point which contains a huge mass in an infinitely small space, where density and gravity become infinite and space-time curves infinitely, and where the laws of physics as we know them cease to operate. Although supermassive black holes do not usually indulge in the process of moving about the universe, smaller black holes do. I have read from various sources that these black holes move at an appreciable speed comparing with light. So my question here is about the increase in mass and density of the black hole further.

By Einstein's equation, the density of the point where the gravitational singularity has been developed and the mass of the black hole should constantly be increasing. Does this imply that at one time, the black hole should grow vast enough to swallow the entire universe and after the "spaghettification" all the mass of the universe gets stored at the infinitely small point with infinite density?

What I further do not understand is, is that how do black holes grow in mass? In my opinion, by swallowing stars, asteroids, etc., the size of black holes should remain constant and the mass of the point where the singularity is developed should be increased. I have also read that when two black holes crash into each other, their gravitational fields combine to create an even stronger gravitational field.

In this case, are the black holes superposing on each other by pure constructive interference?

Kindly help me with the same.

Comment: Hello! Please try to focus more - you are currently asking multiple questions in one post. You can always [edit] your question to specify it or [ask a new one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Thanks!

Comment: Your question is based on a false intuition. A Schwarzschild singularity is not a point, but an infinitely long straight coordinate line. It has no properties of mass, volume, or density, contains no matter, and causes no gravity inside or outside the black hole. Also, the gravitational equations do not require the mass of a black hole to be constantly increasing. This site requires questions based on an effort to study, not on personal theories. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer this as best I can, however in order to do that I will need to explain briefly how Black Holes were 'discovered'. The Schwarzschild Solution is the general metric for a spherically symmetry static space-time that satisfies the Einstein Equations. It also yields Newtonian gravity in the 'Newtonian Limit'. If you are not familiar with these concepts then my post will not be very useful, so I would recommend finding a course on GR. Perhaps use David Tongs notes which can be found [here.](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gr.html)

The Schwarzschild solution is as follows:

$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\dfrac{2M}{r}\right)dt^2+\left(1-\dfrac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2,$$
where M is the mass of the "star" or body at the centre of your spacetime, r is the radial coordinate from the centre and $d\Omega^2$ is the metric on $S^2$. As you can see, the term in front of the $dr^2$ term has a problem, specifically when r=2M. Approaching this point, the term diverges to infinity. Historically this was seen as an issue with the solution, however it was later seen that this is simply a singularity that arose from the coordinate basis and not a curvature singularity in the space time (like the one which occurs at r=0). The point r=2M actually corresponds to the *event horizon.* Light rays travelling within this boundary cannot escape outside the boundary. I will not repeat the calculations here as they are very common and can be found online.

You can see that as mass of the black hole increases so does the radius. As such the area of the event horizon, $A=4\pi R $ (where R=2M is the radius of our BH) increases also. This is actually a very big issue. The entropy of a black hole is given to be $S=\frac{1}{4}A$. One of the laws of BH thermodynamics states that Black holes cannot decrease in surface area. One can see that as a black hole increases in mass, it also moves towards a higher entropy state. Thermodynamic systems will evolve towards the highest entropy state, meaning that as a black hole takes in matter from the universe, it decreases the entropy of the universe whilst increasing its own. If we associate a temperature with this black hole entropy, then eventually the black hole would grow so large that its temperature would be larger than that of the surrounding universe. But since black holes cannot decrease in surface area, this would imply that energy would be moving from a low temperature state to a high temperature one, violating thermodynamic principles. This is part of the motivation for Hawking Radiation, which is a very interesting subject and has some more readable material published by Hawking.

I hope perhaps this has provided some food for thought, I think that following a course on GR would yield more satisfying answers. It is very difficult to trust your intuition in these matters, sometimes you simply have to listen to the mathematics. Black Holes are not like springs and pendulums, you have to work with the theory.

Answer (score 0):

Physicists are a bit melodramatic about what goes on inside the event horizon. The truth is simply that we do not know. All we know is that the math get rather wonky, which is either math porn or horror depending on your point of view. But from an outside perspective black holes appear to behave consistently with the known laws of physics.

**Do black holes only grow?** They have a simple way of increasing mass by "eating" energy from our universe. But the only known way for them to lose mass is through the painfully slow process of Hawking radiation. So for all practical considerations yes.

**Will all energy in our universe end up inside a mega black hole?** We don't know. Black energy appears to be driving things apart faster than gravity can pull it together. The going theory is that we will eventually get to a point known as the *black hole era* when the only thing populating our universe is roaming black holes.

**How does the event horizon grow?** I think this would be best explained through orbitals. As you move an orbit closer to the center of mass the velocity must increase to stay in orbit. For black holes there is an orbit where the velocity is equal to the speed of light, this happens right at the edge of the event horizon. It is known as the *photo sphere* because we expect photons to be orbiting there. Everything inside that orbit must always be moving inwards because not doing so would require velocities higher than the speed of light. As their apparent mass increases the orbital velocity for a given distance increases in accordance with the known laws of physics. Therefore the photo sphere moves radially outwards and the event horizon along with it.

**Do merging black holes superpose on each other by pure constructive interference?** I think the most intuitive way to look at it is by simply adding their apparent masses together just like you would with any other coalescing mass.